# Is there a way to get Index HTML file name on default server location (Javascript or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I'm trying to find a way to get the name of the current HTML file from URL (or any other possible way. It works most of the time, except for the case when the URL doesn't display the file name :
Works when : http://localhost:8080/Index.html
Doesn't work when : http://localhost:8080/ (hosting server will display index page that way on load).

The following function is the one I currently used. It is inspired from few other questions on StackOverflow talking about getting the filename from the complete URL.

```
function GetOtherLanguageLink(lang){
  var pagename = window.location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  pagename_split = pagename.split('.');
  if (lang == "fr"){
    return pagename_split[0] + "_en." + pagename_split[1];
  }
  else if (lang == "en"){
    return pagename.replace("_en","");
  }
  else{
    return pagename;
  }
}
```

It is pretty simple, for `Index.html` it returns `Index_en.html` and vice versa.
When the URL doesn't have a filename, I get `_en.undefined`.

Is there some other way I could do that to get it work?

PS : if things are unclear, comment (I usually speak french so may not be clear).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well there is no way of knowing what it actually is on the server. You can check to see if array has a length before using it and use what you know what the default is.

Comment: Haven't thought of that.., it works. Thanks a lot!